# CPT and hierarchical Taxonomy in same slug

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy, slug, hierarchical

I have posts with this structure:

> - Collection   (Taxonomy > Term)
> - - Book      (Taxonomy > Child Term)
> - - - Poem    (Custom Post Type)

and want this URL structure:

> site.com/poem/                          (archive of 'poem' CPT)
>
> site.com/poem/collection1/              (archive of 'collection'
>   taxonomy)
>
> site.com/poem/collection1/book1         (archive of 'book1' term)
>
> site.com/poem/collection1/book1/poem1   (show the 'poem1' post)

CPT and taxonomy settings:

CPT:

```
'poem'
    'public'             => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'exclude_from_search'=> false,
    'show_ui'            => true,
    'show_in_menu'       => true,
    'query_var'          => true,
    'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'poem/%collection%', //leaved field blank and custom slug sets with plugin
                                   'with_front' => false),
    'capability_type'    => 'post',
    'has_archive'        => 'poem',
    'hierarchical'       => false
```

Taxonomy:

```
'collection'
    'public'             => true,
    'hierarchical'       => true,
    'query_var'          => true,
    'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'poem',
                                   'with_front' => false,
                                   'hierarchical' => true )
```

I created 'collection1' in collection taxonomy then created and set 'book1' as child of 'collection1'. Also 'poem1' created and 'book1' set as term.

Now I have the url structure that I want but 'poem1' (or any posts in this CPT) get 404 Not Found error.
I searched and tried almost all of the solutions... but doesn't work.

CPT and taxonomy created with *[Pods](https://wordpress.org/plugins/pods/)* Plugin and custom permalink for CPT created with *[Custom Post Type Permalinks](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/)* Plugin.

**Update:**
When I change the taxonomy slug to different with CPT slug (=poem), post's links work correctly.

Comment: What is the name of .php of each template?

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos I'm not create templates for archives. So by default wp use the 'archive.php'. Also I copy archive.php into a new file 'archive-poem.php' (and single.php into single-poem.php) but 404 error not solved.

Comment: Try taxonomy-poem.php, taxonomy-poem-collection1.php and single.php

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos Thanks for your reply. Issue not resolved. I copy 'archive.php' into new file with 'taxonomy-poem.php' and 'taxonomy-poem-collection1.php'. That's all? Should I edit codes? (Please check my update note)

Comment: Try `single-poem.php`, `taxonomy-collection.php`

Comment: I tried that before. Not solved... @AntonisTsimourtos